# Sort results from Get-ChildItem with Get-FileHash before output

Tags: powershell, sorting

I try to write a windows PowerShell script. I need to get file hash from all files in directory tree.

This is what I got so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\path" -Recurse -Force -Attributes !Directory | % {Get-FileHash $_.Fullname} | Out-File "c:\temp\report_file.txt"
```

File `c:\temp\report_file.txt` is something like this:

```
Algorithm Hash Path                                                                         
--------- ---- ----                                                                         
SHA256 E3B0C44298...E4649B934CA495991B7852B855 c:\temp\path\report1.txt                                                        
SHA256 7B989C1C95...6756624B3887E501DCC377DB23 c:\temp\path\report2.txt                                                       
SHA256 EA0155401C...A6D44F1DEBB95E401AEFF4F908 c:\temp\path\report3.txt                                                      
SHA256 06DAA0E452...32E3F3104EA4564EAB67CA6A0A c:\temp\path\report4.txt                                                     
**SHA256 9C7C9FEA96...45F460BA9015C8F0A5CA830B6B c:\temp\path\report5.txt**
```

All works fine.

Expect:
I run this cmdlet a lot of times per day. Files are deleted and re-created from time to time in this directory tree. And... Several times order of files in output file is not the same. 
In the example below file `report5.txt` in report file must be in last line, but it is on second line. I suppose it is because of recurse option is selected. This recurse option is needed for me. When I run cmdlet on directory with no subdirectories, result is equal all the time. But when on directory with subdirectories (directory tree) - not.

```
Algorithm Hash Path                                                                         
--------- ---- ----                                                                         
SHA256 E3B0C44298...E4649B934CA495991B7852B855 c:\temp\path\report1.txt                                                        
**SHA256 9C7C9FEA96...45F460BA9015C8F0A5CA830B6B c:\temp\path\report5.txt**              
SHA256 7B989C1C95...6756624B3887E501DCC377DB23 c:\temp\path\report2.txt                                                       
SHA256 EA0155401C...A6D44F1DEBB95E401AEFF4F908 c:\temp\path\report3.txt                                                      
SHA256 06DAA0E452...32E3F3104EA4564EAB67CA6A0A c:\temp\path\report4.txt
```

Is here a solution to sort somehow all data by column fullpath before data outputed to report file?

Answer (score 10):

You can sort by the path property of the hash object.

You can also run the files directly into `Get-FileHash` without using a loop, and I suggest exporting them to CSV instead of text, so it keeps the algorithm, hash and path separated so you can use them more easily:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp\path" -Recurse -Force -File | 
    Get-FileHash | 
    Sort-Object -Property 'Path' |
    Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\report_file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```